# How do I display all of the attributes from a many-to-many relationship?

Tags: django, templates, view, model, many-to-many

I have 2 models in my Django app that have a many-to-many relationship.  How do I display each of the categories that a product will have?  What do I include in the view and template?

```
class Product(models.Model):
    website = models.CharField('Product name', max_length = 200)
    mutliple_cat = models.ManyToManyField(Multicat, null=True, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.website

class Multicat(models.Model):
    mutlicat = models.CharField('Multi cat', max_length = 200, null=True, blank=True)
    mutlicat_url = models.CharField('Multi cat url', max_length = 200, null=True, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.mutlicat)
```

This is what I have in my view:

```
product = Product.objects.order_by("website")
```

Template:

```
{% for prod in product %}
    {% for cat in prod.multiple_cat.all %}
            {{ cat.multicat }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're passing a Product in a variable named `my_product` to the template:

```
{% for cat in my_product.multiple_cat.all %}
    multicat name: {{ cat.multicat }}
    multicat url: {{ cat.multicat_url }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I included what I have in my view...I'm passing "product".  I tried putting this in the template but nothing happens.  Is something wrong with my view?

Comment: Your `product` is a query set of all products, not a single instance. You'll need to iterate through that in an outer for loop.

Comment: I'm trying that too and it doesn't seem to work.  I edited the question to include the 2 for loops in the template now...is the for loop constructed incorrectly?